# Find Referring Pages without Google Analytics

Tags: google, referrer

is there a way to find referring pages to a URL?

Example: Page A links to Page B. I know the URL of Page B but want to find out about Page A, which links to Page B.

Can I perform this via Google Search somehow?

Comment: Do you have access to Google Webmaster Tools?   How about your web servers access logs?

Comment: Nope, this is why I am asking. I want to find out which sites link to a certain page that I do not own.

Comment: This is about using other websites rather than about running your own.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you know about links to a site from Google Search:

**Edit:** Type 'link:http://your_site_B.com' (on your Google Search box).

Please read this short Google article: [Links to your Site](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/55281?hl=en)

Comment: This is not an answer to a question. If a link you provided goes 404 no one will be able to gain anything from your response.